# Tensorflow Lite responses are incorrect

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Im trying to implement **tflite** into **flutter** using **YAMNET** model, the thing is the responses are not correct not even close actually.

I give a some random sound wav files and the response is completely off ,for example i give cat sounds and it gives me silence as a response from my txt table, with biggest score than **"roar"** for example .What is the issue here, do i have false txt format files,or my code have bugs?

Here is my code ,thanks in adnvance :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:tflite_flutter/tflite_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class Mic2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  Mic2State createState() => Mic2State();
}

class Mic2State extends State<Mic2> {
  late Interpreter interpreter;
  List<String> labels = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadModel();
    loadLabels();
  }

  Future<void> loadModel() async {
    try {
      interpreter = await Interpreter.fromAsset('assets/xxx.tflite',
          options: InterpreterOptions()..threads = 4);

      print('Model loaded successfully');
    } catch (error) {
      print('Something Went Wrong');
    }
  }

  Future<void> loadLabels() async {
    try {
      String labelsContent = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/xxx.txt');
      labels = labelsContent.split('\n').map((e) => e.trim()).toList();
      print('Labels loaded successfully');
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error loading labels: $error');
    }
  }

  Future<void> runInferenceWithAudio() async {
    ByteData audioData = await rootBundle.load('assets/xxx.wav');
    List<int> audioBytes = audioData.buffer.asUint8List();
    List<double> normalizedAudio = normalizeAudioData(audioBytes, 15600);

    var input = [normalizedAudio];
    var output = List.filled(521, 0).reshape([1, 521]);

    try {
      interpreter.runForMultipleInputs([input], {0: output});
      print('Output Tensor Length: ${output[0].length}');
      print('Writing Output Tensor to file...');
      writeArrayToFile(output[0], 'output_tensor.txt');
      print('Input Audio Length: ${input[0].length}');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error during inference: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> writeArrayToFile(List<double> array, String filename) async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final filePath = '${directory.path}/$filename';

    final File file = File(filePath);
    file.writeAsStringSync(array.map((e) => e.toString()).join('\n'));
    print('Output Tensor written to $filePath');
  }

  List<double> normalizeAudioData(List<int> audioBytes, int targetSize) {
    // Example: Normalize to values between -1 and 1
    List<double> normalizedAudio =
        audioBytes.map((value) => value / 32767.0).toList();
    normalizedAudio = List.from(normalizedAudio.take(targetSize));

    return normalizedAudio;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    interpreter.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Text('Mic'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            await runInferenceWithAudio();
          },
          child: Text('Classify Audio'),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    );
  }
}
```

My txt is like this :

```
Speech
Child speech, kid speaking
Conversation
Narration, monologue
Babbling
Speech synthesizer
Shout
Bellow
```

I've also tried to make the txt same with the csv i found on github :

```
0   /m/09x0r    Speech
1   /m/0ytgt    "Child speech, kid speaking"
2   /m/01h8n0   Conversation
3   /m/02qldy   "Narration, monologue"
4   /m/0261r1   Babbling
5   /m/0brhx    Speech synthesizer
6   /m/07p6fty  Shout
7   /m/07q4ntr  Bellow
```